# Does firebase app check with play integrity requires an app in the store

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I can't manage to make a release version of a flutter app to correctly identify with app check using the play integrity provider.

As I read, the play integrity verifies that the app has been downloaded from the play store, which in my case, it is not. It's simply run locally as a release build.

So my questions:

- Does app check with play integrity requires the app to be in the play store ?
- If the answer to the above is yes: How can you enforce app check before release and send the app to testers without using the debug token ? Using a debug token would be impractical for testers who are not necessarily techies.